# This interface is not not supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE))

Tags: c#, .net, interface, com

I want to take advantage of Leica library allowing to get Leica Disto lasermeter device measurements. It's some new model equipped with BT Smart.
They deliver Disto Transfer PC software. It makes all the job for device-PC connection. It's possible to get measurements from this software into other one.

I implemented it some time ago and it worked. But now (maybe Disto Transfer PC has been updated???) I got such error when trying to create Disto4.Disto4() object.

I receive such error message:
Unable to cast COM object of a type of 'System .__ ComObject' to interface type 'Disto4.Disto4'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{C19D78CB-466D-420F-BC58-930B7B49B5A4}' failed due to the following error: This interface is not not supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

What I did to arrange everything:

1. I installed Disto Transfer PC (SetupDISTO4_402.exe)
2. I launched it as an administrator. COM class has been registered.
3. I registered Disto40.tlb with regtlibv12.exe
4. I added reference in my C# project selecting Disto40.tlb from the folder where Disto transfer 40 was installed.
5. Interop.Disto4.dll file has been created.
6. When `Disto4.Disto4 distoApp = new Disto4.Disto4();` command is run it launches Disto Transfer PC successfully but then throws an exception like mentioned above.

It's strange because one year ago it worked well. It was tested on Windows 8.1.
Now we tried to check it on Windows 10 but it turned out there is also an issue with Windows 8.1.

It's WinForms app.

I have [STAThread] before Main() method.

I tried to build it for x64 and x86.

I appreciate if you could help.

Myzzard